# Does `bytearray` not contradict the Zen of Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arrays

Python [PEP 3137](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3137/) introduced [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) as a mutable 8-bit array type. However, a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#list) of the immutable [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes) type accomplishes the same goal, and actually has [better](http://dabeaz.blogspot.co.il/2010/01/few-useful-bytearray-tricks.html) [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162609/python-bytearray-verses-list-of-bytes#), albeit perhaps a clunkier syntax. This new type contradicts the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

So my question is: is there any documented major advantage or design consideration for using a `bytearray` over a `list` of `bytes`?

So far, I have not found a piece of motivation documented in the PEP or in the documentation pages. In fact, the documentation treats them as near-equals:

> The bytearray type is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256. It has most of the usual methods of mutable sequences...

And then,

> List and bytearray objects support additional operations that allow in-place modification of the object. Other mutable sequence types (when added to the language) should also support these operations.

As `bytearray`s are statically typed (as 8-bit unsigned integers) one might expect a performance increase, but as mentioned above the inverse is probably true. Also, there should be no memory advantage for a `bytearray` over a `list` of `bytes`. I could imagine that there was a need to a `itertools.chain`-style mutable type, but this is not mentioned anywhere and does not seem to be the design goal.

Comment: A bytearray can do things that a list cannot

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, you should probably be using NumPy.

Comment: Also, I find this dubious: "Also, there should be no memory advantage for a bytearray over a list of bytes." A `list` is going to contain a reference (4 or 8 bytes depending on platform) to each `bytes` value, which is stored elsewhere. A `bytearray` is going to use exactly 1 byte per value. This should be a significant memory savings.

Comment: have you seen [the interface supported by `bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binaryseq)? It is quite different from the generic `list`. You might as well ask, why `bytes` exists if we could put bytes into a `tuple`. `bytearray` is mutable sequence of bytes. `bytes` is an immutable sequence of bytes.

Comment: @kindall - `bytearray` should probably be implemented as non-contiguous memory; otherwise you suffer from reallocation with every call to `extend()` and then we might as well have concatendated `bytes` together.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I agree that there is advantage to use `bytearray` over `list` in the syntax sense, but I wonder if it's enough to warrant a new construct such as `bytearray`. To add to that, you have, on the other hand, the [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) construct, which also makes `bytearray` look redundant.

Comment: @Yuval: again, the interface provided by `array.array()` is substantially different from `bytearray()`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I agree that it is different, though not substantially. Why shouldn't they be identical?

Comment: @Yuval do you understand why array.array has no `.upper()` method while bytearray has?

Comment: @Yuval: If `bytearray`'s method `extend()` suffers from reallocation, then the `list` suffers the same way as it is implemented as a contiguous array of references.

Answer (score 0):

First,  a `list`-style container for sequences of objects that can seamlessly iterate through them (something that `itertools.chain` provides, actually) definitely seems convenient. As [PEP 3137](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3137/) mentions, the [array module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) might have served for this purpose, but was "far from ideal".

The authors wished for "both a mutable and an immutable bytes type", which might mean that the design goal was having the same interface for both a mutable (perhaps using non-contiguous memory for fast insertions and deletions), as well as an immutable (definitely contiguous memory) implementation. This created, as far as I can appreciate, a jumble of sequence types, including `array.array`, `bytes`, `bytearray`, `str`, `unicode`, `list`, `tuple` and `generator`. In essence, they provide interfaces to statically typed or ducked type, mutable or unmutable sequences which are stored in memory or evaluated on-the-fly (generators). Most of these do follow the rationale of the [Abstract Base Classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119), but I do think that there is more design to be done before this can be deemed Pythonic.

Note: I'm leaving this answer open for editing hoping that people might contribute insights or corrections.